# C# Arithmetic Question

Tags: c#, math, overflow

Good afternoon,

Having never used C# to do serious mathematical work, I have just noticed something which left me confused... If it is true that

```
double Test = Math.Sqrt(UInt64.MaxValue)
```

is equal to 4294967296.0, that is, `UInt32.MaxValue + 1`, why is it that

```
ulong Test2 = UInt32.MaxValue * UInt32.MaxValue;
```

is equal to 1? At first sight it seems to me that overflow occurs here... But why is that since that product should fit a `UInt64`?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

the first one happens because double doesn't have 64 mantissa bits, but only around 53. So `UInt64.MaxValue` will be rounded to `UInt64.MaxValue+1` during the conversion to `double`. And the `Sqrt` of that is obviously 2^32. `double` can represent any value from `(U)Int32` exactly, but some of the larger 64 bit integers can't be represented as `double`.

The second one happens because you do the multiplication before casting to `UInt64`, i.e. it happens as `UInt32`, which obviously overflows. Cast at least one of your operands to `UInt64` and the problem will disappear.

Comment: True. Please give -1 to my question. And thank you very much.

Comment: @Miguel: I don't think you need to -1.  You made an honest mistake.  The question's been answered and that's that.

Comment: The question was clearly formulated, so I have no complaint. And I made similar mistakes myself too.

Comment: @Miguel, keep this in mind in more scenarios than just math. The expression on the right is not affected by the type on the left. The expression on the right has a type of its own (and if it does not, it will produce an error).

Answer (score 4):

```
ulong Test2 = UInt32.MaxValue * UInt32.MaxValue
```

Could be translated to :

```
UInt32 __temp = UInt32.MaxValue * UInt32.MaxValue; // Overflow
ulong Test2 = (ulong)__temp;
```

as thee operation on the left of the = sign is always done without any inference on the type on the right obviously not what you want...

It should have been

```
ulong Test2 = (long)UInt32.MaxValue * UInt32.MaxValue;
```

That will be treated as  :

```
ulong Test2 = (long)UInt32.MaxValue * (long)UInt32.MaxValue;
```

And will work.

The rules are in section 16.4.2 of the C# norm :

> Numeric promotion consists of
>   automatically performing certain
>   implicit conversions of the operands
>   of the  predefined unary and binary
>   numeric operators. Numeric promotion
>   is not a distinct mechanism, but
>   rather  an effect of applying overload
>   resolution to the predefined
>   operators. Numeric promotion
>   specifically does  not affect
>   evaluation of user-defined operators,
>   although user-defined operators can be
>   implemented to  exhibit similar
>   effects.
>
> As an example of numeric promotion,
>   consider the predefined
>   implementations of the binary *
>   operator:
>
> ```
> int operator *(int x, int y); 
> uint operator *(uint x, uint y); 
> long operator *(long x, long y); 
> ulong operator *(ulong x, ulong y); 
> void operator *(long x, ulong y); 
> void operator *(ulong x, long y); 
> float operator *(float x, float y); 
> double operator *(double x, double y); 
> decimal operator *(decimal x, decimal y);
> ```
>
> When overload resolution rules
>   (§14.4.2) are applied to this set of
>   operators, the effect is to select the
>   first of  the operators for which
>   implicit conversions exist from the
>   operand types. [Example: For the
>   operation  b * s, where b is a byte
>   and s is a short, overload resolution
>   selects operator *(int, int) as the 
>   best operator. Thus, the effect is
>   that b and s are converted to int, and
>   the type of the result is int. 
>   Likewise, for the operation i * d,
>   where i is an int and d is a double,
>   overload resolution selects  operator
>   *(double, double) as the best operator. end example]